# R cut function for strings

Tags: r, performance

I am wondering if there is any function in R that is similar to the cut function but works on strings?

The code I am working on is to assign data concerning states in the U.S. to a categorical variable called Region: there are 4 regions Northeast, Midwest, South, West. The data frame storing each of the data stores the state name in a variable called "state" and in it's abbreviated form: "NY" for New York or "MS" for Mississippi, for example. The region variable needs to be added to the data frame, which I am currently doing as follows (this is for homework so I want to show that I already do have a solution and am just looking for a potentially better one):

```
create.region <- function(state) {
northeast <- c("CT", "ME", "MA", "NH", "RI", "VT", "NJ", "NY", "PA")
midwest <- c("IL", "IN", "MI", "OH", "WI", "IA", "KS", "MN", "MO", "NE", "ND", "SD")
south <- c("DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "MD", "NC", "SC", "VA", "WV", "AL", "KY", "TN", "MS", "AR", "LA", "OK", "TX")
west <- c("AZ", "CO", "ID", "MT", "NV", "NM", "UT", "WY", "AK", "CA", "HI", "OR", "WA")
region <- ifelse(state %in% northeast, "Northeast", 
          ifelse(state %in% midwest, "Midwest",
          ifelse(state %in% south, "South",
          ifelse(state %in% west, "West", NA ))))
return(region)
}
birth_data <- within(birth_data, region <- create.region(state))
```

I don't know a lot about R yet and I am concerned with the efficiency of my code. I have found in the past that the cut function is a more concise and efficient way of categorizing numeric data in this manner, but it apparently does not work with character vectors. Is there any function similar to cut that allows for a character assignment rule, rather than numeric ones only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to map the names via a vector.

First, we prepare the map:

```
all_states = c('northeast', 'midwest', 'south', 'west')

states_for_region = function (region) {
    states = get(region)
    setNames(rep(region, length(states)), states)
}

states_map = unlist(lapply(all_states, states_for_region))
```

We could also have constructed the `states_map` manually for each region, and then concatenate the results. But the above is less repetitive.

Then, we do the actual mapping, which now requires only a single line.

```
region = states_map[state]
```

For efficiency, it’s a good idea to prepare the map *outside* of the function. Otherwise it will be regenerated whenever you call that function.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box R includes variables `state.abb` and `state.region`.  The former is a character vector of all state abbreviations and the latter is a 4 level factor of the same length containing the corresponding regions; therefore, to get the region for MS, say:

```
state.region[state.abb == "MS"]
## [1] South
## Levels: Northeast South North Central West
```

If you want a different categorization it would be easy enough to define your own alternative to `state.region` and then use the code above.

As an aside, note that `state.name` also exists which is the same length as the above two variables and gives the full state name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `levels<-` function along with your list of mappings.

Here's an example:

```
## Create your mapping....
## Overkill in this example as @Grothendieck has pointed out,
##   but still applicable in a general scenario

myLevs <- list(
  Northeast = c("CT", "ME", "MA", "NH", "RI", "VT", "NJ", "NY", "PA"), 
  Midwest = c("IL", "IN", "MI", "OH", "WI", "IA", "KS", "MN", "MO", "NE", "ND", "SD"), 
  South = c("DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "MD", "NC", "SC", "VA", "WV", "AL", "KY", "TN", "MS", "AR", "LA", "OK", "TX"), 
  West = c("AZ", "CO", "ID", "MT", "NV", "NM", "UT", "WY", "AK", "CA", "HI", "OR", "WA"))
```

Now, create a sample vector:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(state.abb, 10)
```

`factor` the vector, and change its `levels`. This can be done in two steps (`y <- factor(x); levels(y) <- myLevs)` or in one step with the nice cryptic-looking:

```
y <- `levels<-`(factor(x), myLevs)
```

Here's the output:

```
x
#  [1] "IN" "ME" "NV" "TX" "GA" "SD" "TN" "NH" "NE" "AZ"
y
#  [1] Midwest   Northeast West      South     South     Midwest   South    
#  [8] Northeast Midwest   West     
# Levels: Northeast Midwest South West
```

Comment: can you explain more in details the one step method?
I don't understand the  ` ` in `levels<-` part